# Pilcrow Sign problem on Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-word-2007

We have a user in our office having problem with Pilcrow signs (¶) on Outlook 2007. They appear when she tries create a new mail. We uncheck the Pilcrow sign option from outlook but every now or then they show up again when she creates a new mail. Without user selecting that option.

So I deleted her normal.dot file from Application Data\Microsoft\Templates directory. Since she was using Word 2007 as mail editor.But that didn't help.

As a last resort we reinstalled Office 2007 to her machine. But that didn't help either, she is still having the same problem, signs appear every time she creates a new mail.

Is there any other way permanently removing this sign?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> and that should turn it off.

Alternatively look under the FILE tab on the toolbar and it will be under there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I was able to resolve it.

Open a new email page (don't go to the Generic Tools option of Outlook itself) -> Tools -> Options -> View Tab, under Formatting Marks, uncheck everything, and the Pilcrow sign should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Does the pilcrow appear when she starts up Word 2007 itself (not just within Outlook)? If so, then make sure that (1) she deselects the button for this (on the Home tab of the ribbon, in the Paragraph section), and (2) if it still appears onscreen, go to Office Button > Word Options > Display, and deselect Paragraph marks.

The settings for Word should then carry over to Outlook.

Comment: Pilcrow isn't appearing on word when we open a new document. It only appears on Outlook when she tries to create a new mail, replying a message and forwarding a message. I also checked formatting options in editor options, it's unchecked. We don't have any problem turning them off. The problem is they show up again after restarting the program, system etc. no matter what we do.